# Argument of type 'numpy.int64' is not iterable. For with if x not in list

Tags: python, list, numpy, for-loop, if-statement

```
categories = list()

for i in range (len(purchases_reader)): 
    purchase_type = purchases_reader.iloc[i, 3]
    if purchase_type not in categories:
        categories = purchase_type
    print (categories)
```

I want to check if the value purchase_type exists in the list categories before the value is inserted to the list

Comment: Always post what line you are getting error with full traceback. It will help others debugging.

Comment: I'm getting the error at - if purchase_type not in categories:

Comment: After `if purchase_type not in categories: categories = purchase_type`, the name `categories` may very well get bound to a `numpy.int64` referred to by `purchase_type`. Did you mean `categories.append(purchase_type)`?

Comment: By saying `categories = purchase_type`, your next iteration will fail because `categories` is no longer a list and therefore doesn't support `in`

Comment: If I use `categories.append(purchase_type)` the error goes away, but my output is `[452, 449, 448, 451, 442, 417, 560, 444, 686, 447, 443, 530, 554, 543, 545, 667, 694, 542, 537, 693, 685, 778, 750, 539, 826, 684, 688, 883, 681, 786, 1017, 1018, 1043, 780, 690]
[452, 449, 448, 451, 442, 417, 560, 444, 686, 447, 443, 530, 554, 543, 545, 667, 694, 542, 537, 693, 685, 778, 750, 539, 826, 684, 688, 883, 681, 786, 1017, 1018, 1043, 780, 690]` the same same thing gets repeated on and on

Comment: Have you considered using a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)? You could then probably replace the if statement with `categories.add(purchage_type)`

Comment: The problem got solved after using append. Later, the issue was that I didn't use print in the right place